# Find and add multiple objects scores to be closest to a given value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of objects as:

```
[
  {
    score: 1,
  },
  {
    score: 2,
  },
  {
    score: 4,
  },
]
```

And I have a given value, a number.

e.g.: value is **6**

My goal is to take objects so their score (added themself) to be closest to the value (here: **6**)

My first step is to check if an object score is equal to the value.

If it's not the case, I have no idea how I can achieve this.

With the array above, for **6** I would need to pick the second and the third because it's the only combination where the added scores is equal to **6** (4 + 2)

But, imagine the third object's score is 3, I would need to pick the 3 objects to obtain **6**.

Sometimes I cannot get the value so I just need to be the closest one.

I don't want You to create an algorithm but I need to know what path I should follow to achieve this efficiently because I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Think of it as a binary problem. Each object is either in or out of the party. Besides that, you must at least be familiar with the concept of recursive programming. Are you?

Comment: do you have greater values or negative? do you only want to get the sum or the objects?

Comment: I know what is recursive function in JS, that's all. 
Given value is > 0 and scores are >= 0.

Comment: Use recursion.

Basically start with a function call that checks the first score. If it's greater than or equal to the final score, then return that value. If it is less than the score, then call the function again, with the new score passed as an argument. If the next score plus the previous score is greater than or equal to the score, return the value. If not, keep going until the score is greater than or equal to the value.

Comment: Now, you also have to check what final score is closest, not necessarily which is greater (for example you could get 10 as the greater value, while the lesser value is 5, which is closer, so in that case, you would need to pick 5).

Comment: So to solve this you need to do the same thing, again, in reverse. Start with a function call (different function) to the first score value. If it is equal to or less than the final score value, return it. If it is greater than the final score, move on, and call the same function again, with the previous score as a parameter. If the new score plus the previous score just checked is less than or equal to the final value, then return it. If it is greater, then keep going until you have reached the end.

Comment: If you have reached the end and all of the values added are still greater, then just return the last value.

Now you have a total of 2 returned values, from these two different functions. Now you just have to compare the distance between each value to the final score, i.e., the absolute value. Say your score is 6, and one result is 8 and another is 4. So take a variable list distHigher and set it equal to 8 - 6, then make another variable, distLower, and set it equal to 6 - 4, then just determine which number is smaller, and that is your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursion.

Basically start with a function call that checks the first score. If it's greater than or equal to the final score, then return that value. If it is less than the score, then call the function again, with the new score passed as an argument. If the next score plus the previous score is greater than or equal to the score, return the value. If not, keep going until the score is greater than or equal to the value.

Now, you also have to check what final score is *closest*, not necessarily which is greater (for example you could get 10 as the greater value, while the lesser value is 5, which is closer, so in that case, you would need to pick 5).

So to solve this you need to do the same thing, again, in reverse. Start with a function call (different function) to the first score value. If it is equal to or less than the final score value, return it. If it is greater than the final score, move on, and call the same function again, with the previous score as a parameter. If the new score plus the previous score just checked is less than or equal to the final value, then return it. If it is greater, then keep going until you have reached the end. If you have reached the end and all of the values added are still greater, then just return the last value.

Now you have a total of 2 returned values, from these two different functions. Now you just have to compare the distance between each value to the final score, i.e., the absolute value. Say your score is **6**, and one result is **8** and another is **4**. So take a variable list `distHigher` and set it equal to `8 - 6`, then make another variable, `distLower`, and set it equal to `6 - 4`, then just determine which number is smaller, and that is your answer.